# Mobile devices are loading old version of website

Tags: html, caching, mobile, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

:)

I have multiple static containers on my website which link to files such as

```
<div class="logo_footer"><a href="#"><img src="/img/cms/logo_footer.png" alt="" 
/> </a></div>
```

I recently changed from my servers IP to an domain and had to change the url accordingly given how previously, there was a /website/ infront of the /img/cms/logo_footer.png.

The changes work flawlessly on desktops however, on multiple mobiles, even after clearing the cache, the website still tries to load the old files at /img/cms/logo_footer.png rather than the changed /cms/logo_footer.png

Even if I ask for the desktop version. I've tried on multiple devices, even some that haven't yet visited the website on the new url.

If it were some sort of plug in I'd be guessing that the link for the mobile version of the link might be different but it's literally just the mentioned html  in a static container.

I'm running LAMP und Ubuntu 16 and am using Prestashop 1.7 with cache disabled and emptied. I also have recompiled the theme in there.

Comment: You said you cleared the cache. Do you mean the browser cache? If so, do you have a server-side cache?

Comment: I cleared the browser cache aswell as the websites cache. I also changed the link to an external url to see if something internal went wrong. While the amazon logo was displayed on the desktop version, the mobile version still linked to the /website/img/cmd/logo_footer.png file, which isn't a thing anymore, given that the url links to IP/website/ by default. Thus, it' end up in IP/website/website/img/cmd/logo_footer.png

Comment: It just now ended up working. I haven't even had a CDN service in place that could've explained it. But, oh well. I'm happy.

Comment: I am happy the problem was solved, but I still think some cache was involved.